# Function iteration with Async waterfall in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to get resource from the some url, that resource is separated as multiple pages, the number of page is over 500, but the order of resource have to be guaranteed, so I decided to use Async module.

```
function getData(page, callback){
    var url = "http://someurl.com/document?page="+page;
    // get data from the url ...
    // when success, 
    callback();
};
```

So, above function is get resource from some url, I have to iterate this function to many times, but I don't know how can I iterate this with async waterfall. What point I should push the **for** iteration?

```
async.waterfall([

    // page 1 
    function(callback){
        getData(1, function(){
            callback(null);
        });
    },

    // page 2
    function(callback){
        getData(2, function(){
            callback(null);
        });
    },

    // page 3, 4, 5..... 100, ... 500


],function(err, result){
    if(err) return next();

    console.log('finish !');
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't even use `for`, use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use Promises:

```
function getData(page, callback){
    var url = "http://someurl.com/document?page="+page;
    // var request = call to get data from the url ... 
    return request;
};

var promises = [];

for (var page = 1; page < totalPages; page++) {
    promises.push(getData(page));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function (listOfResults) {
    // Do callback here
});
```

Just make sure that your method of sending the get request returns a promise. If not you can use a function like this:

```
function usesCallback(data, callback) {
    // Do something with data
    callback();
}

function makePromise(data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        usesCallback(data, resolve);
    });
}
```

[Here](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) is some more info on Promises

Comment: Promises is not good enough for this. Promises only implement `promise.all` as a flow control method which is equivalent to `async.parallel`. And only that. The async.js library on the other hand provides many other algorithms to process async functions: parallel, series, waterfall, whilst (while), during, until etc. If you prefer the promise design pattern there is a promisified version of async.js called async-q

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use `async`, `async.map()` and `async.mapLimit()` are better choices since they apply the `iteratee` to each item in parallel and guarantee the results array to be in the same order as the original collection.

```
async.mapLimit(_.range(1, 500), 10, getData, function (err, results) {
    // do something with results
});
```

The code above means to get data from page 1 to page 500, with no more than 10 async operations at a time.

`_.range(1, 500)` is a function from `underscore` to generate an array `[1, 2, 3, ..., 500]`. If you do not like to use `underscore` in your project, you can simply rewrite it such as:

```
function range(lower, upper) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(upper - lower + 1))
        .map(function (_, i) { return lower + i; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async's **whilst** for this [check here](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.whilst).